# ArrayList of ArrayList returning incorrect data

Tags: java, android, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I'm currently making an android app which requires that some amount of data is held temporarily as an arraylist of arraylists (string), however when trying to get my head round them, and so adding dummy data and printing it to the depug stream, I don't get the data that I was expecting, but the last added row of data three times. If that does make sense here is the code.

```
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> module_list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> new_row = new ArrayList<String>();

    new_row.add(module_description,"Description0");
    new_row.add(module_address, "Address0");
    new_row.add(module_type, "Type0");
    module_list.add(0,new_row);

    new_row.add(module_description, "Description1");
    new_row.add(module_address,"Address1");
    new_row.add(module_type, "Type1");
    module_list.add(1,new_row);

    new_row.add(module_description, "Description2");
    new_row.add(module_address, "Address2");
    new_row.add(module_type,"Type2");;
    module_list.add(2, new_row);


    for(int row = 0; row<module_list.size() ; row++) {
        ArrayList<String> returned_row = new ArrayList<String>();
        returned_row = module_list.get(row);

        Log.d("APP", "Row: "+ Integer.toString(row));
        Log.d("APP", "Module description: " + returned_row.get(module_description));
        Log.d("APP", "Module address: " + returned_row.get(module_address));
        Log.d("APP", "Module type: " + returned_row.get(module_type));
    }
```

I was intending to print the contents of each row of the arraylist in turn, but instead get:

```
Row: 0
Module description: Description2
Module address: Address2
Module type: Type2
Row: 1
Module description: Description2
Module address: Address2
Module type: Type2
Row: 2
Module description: Description2
Module address: Address2
Module type: Type2
```

Which is the last row added, but in place of all the rows. Has anybody had any problems like this before? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to intialize the **new_row** each time before adding to **module_list**

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> module_list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> new_row = new ArrayList<String>();

        new_row.add(module_description,"Description0");
        new_row.add(module_address, "Address0");
        new_row.add(module_type, "Type0");
        module_list.add(0,new_row);

        new_row = new ArrayList<String>();
        new_row.add(module_description, "Description1");
        new_row.add(module_address,"Address1");
        new_row.add(module_type, "Type1");
        module_list.add(1,new_row);

        new_row = new ArrayList<String>();
        new_row.add(module_description, "Description2");
        new_row.add(module_address, "Address2");
        new_row.add(module_type,"Type2");;
        module_list.add(2, new_row);


        for(int row = 0; row<module_list.size() ; row++) {
            ArrayList<String> returned_row = new ArrayList<String>();
            returned_row = module_list.get(row);

            Log.d("APP", "Row: "+ Integer.toString(row));
            Log.d("APP", "Module description: " + returned_row.get(module_description));
            Log.d("APP", "Module address: " + returned_row.get(module_address));
            Log.d("APP", "Module type: " + returned_row.get(module_type));
        }
```

if you not initialize it then it will override the value for the existing key.

Comment: you are most welcome.

Comment: Instead of new_row = new ArrayList<String>(); you can use new_row.clear();

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>> module_list =      new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<String>>();
ArrayList<String> new_row = new ArrayList<String>();

new_row.add(module_description,"Description0");
new_row.add(module_address, "Address0");
new_row.add(module_type, "Type0");
module_list.put(0,new_row);

new_row.add(module_description, "Description1");
new_row.add(module_address,"Address1");
new_row.add(module_type, "Type1");
module_list.put(1,new_row);

new_row.add(module_description, "Description2");
new_row.add(module_address, "Address2");
new_row.add(module_type,"Type2");;
module_list.put(2, new_row);
```

Comment: Didn't work, I also tried a hashmap of hashmaps but had the same result. Thank you for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:
module_list.add(0,new_row);
Can you check using 
module_list.add(new_row);
As Arraylist is an ordered set, you do not need to give the index.

Comment: No, didn't work :( thank you though!